# Make the currently active tab button stay in front of the border

Tags: html, css

I am working on a tabbing system for my website like in the image below.

[image]

Here is my mark-up and LESS code:

```
<div class="tabsWrapper">
  <div class="tabbar">
    <div class="tabbarButton current" id="tArticles">
      <img class="icon" src="/res/img/articles_archive.png" alt=""/>
      <span class="caption">Arhivă de articole</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbarButton" id="tFiles">
      <img class="icon" src="/res/img/files_archive.png" alt=""/>
      <span class="caption">Arhivă de fișiere</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabsContent">
    <div class="tab current" id="articles"></div>
    <div class="tab" id="files"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

LESS (see full code [here](http://pastebin.com/jk9tcSKe))

```
.tabbar {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  > .tabbarButton {
    height: 45px;

    border-top: 1px solid #bfc2c2;
    border-right: 1px solid #bfc2c2;

    &:first-child { border-left: 1px solid #bfc2c2; }
    &:hover {
      box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 #bfc2c2;
    }
    &.current {
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f5f8f8, inset 0 3px 0 #a7aaaa;
      border-top: 1px solid #a7aaaa;
      background-color: #f5f8f8;
    }
  }
}
> .tabsContent {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfc2c2;
  border-left: 1px solid #bfc2c2;
  border-right: 1px solid #bfc2c2;
  border-top: 1px solid #bfc2c2;

  background-color: #f5f8f8;
}
```

How can I make the currently active tab button to stay *in front* of the others?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to add a :after or :before to the tab, with the same width and same background-color but on the forground.
To be sure, if tabbar is positonned relatively, you can positione your :after absolutely so that it's always ok !
I don't understand why your box-shadow-solution doesn't work..

```
.tabbarButton.current:after
```

Did you tried to pass your current tab on the forground ? (z-index, translateZ...)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself how to achieve the effect I want: by *faking* the bottom border of the tabs-strip:

Modify the `.tabsContent` to not have `border-top`, then provide `.tabbar` class with a `:after` pseudo-element:

```
.tabbar {
  // truncated code
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';

    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfc2c2;
  }
}
```

It is important to change the `z-index` of `.tabbarButton` to `2` (for example) so that it stays in front of the `.tabbar:after`.